# I want to extract the available timing from a table, where the booked timing is stored in another

Tags: sql

My requirement is that I need to know the left over appointment timing from one table, for which the options are available in another table.
Options are available in this table

Options are available in this table

```
Timeid  Timing
==========================
1   | 00:00.0
----------------------------
2   | 00:00.0
-------------------------
3   | 00:00.0
--------------------------
4   | 30:00.0
------------------------------
5   | 30:00.0
-------------------------
6   | 30:00.0
-----------------------
7   | 30:00.0
------------------------
8   | 30:00.0
-------------------------
```

And the Booking saves in the following table

Booking saves in the following table

```
TreaterID   DateBooked  TimeID
----------------------------------------
1   |2012-01-01 |8
----------------------------------
1   |2012-01-01 |3
-------------------------------------
```

I want the result to be the timing from timing table, that is not in Booking table on a particular date.
I am new to programming and could only thing of this solution

```
SELECT Timing FROM ClinicNew.tbl_timing
    WHERE Timeid <>(SELECT Timeid FROM ClinicNew.TreaterEngagedDTM WHERE DateBooked = '02-01-2012')
```

This query does not give me a right solution -  meaning it returns blank when the date is not available in the table-2. It works fine if the date is available at least once.
Please help with this query, or give a different appropriate solution for my requirement.

Comment: Is `DateBooked` a date-only field or a date/time field? If it's a date/time field then `DateBooked = '02-01-2012'` isn't going to work. Also, the date formats aren't the same `02-01-2012` does not equal `2012-01-02`.

Comment: DateBooked is a Date Field and yes I observed the difference but I think I can manage that. Issue stands with Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT timing 
FROM   clinicnew.tbl_timing T 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   clinicnew.treaterengageddtm B 
                   WHERE  B.datebooked = '02-01-2012' 
                          AND T.timeid = B.timeid)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f4c0/4/0)

So result is:

```
TIMING
00:00.0
00:00.0
30:00.0
30:00.0
30:00.0
30:00.0
```

two records are excluded (note that i have changed the date in the demo to the date in the table to demonstrate that the `NOT EXISTS` works, with your date all records would be returned anyway).

Comment: NOT EXISTS ? Is that a SQL Server? cos it gives me an error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.

Comment: I tried NOT LIKE... ad it also has same problem. It does not select anything, if the date is not available in the table2.

Comment: @SyedSohailAhmed: Yes, it is valid SQL syntax also in SQL-Server. Adedd a sql-fiddle demo to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Timing
FROM ClinicNew.tbl_timing t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ClinicNew.TreaterEngagedDTM t2
                 WHERE t2.TimeId = t1.TimeId
                 AND t2.DateBooked = '2012-01-02')
```

Comment: NOT Exists does not work in SQL SERVER. It gave an error - **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.**
I tried NOT LIKE... ad it also has same problem. It does not select anything, if the date is not available in the table2.